# link element inside table td won't expand to fill whole line

Tags: css, hyperlink

In the following example the gray "td" bar will fill the entire window width, but I can't get the encapsulated link to. I want the entire bar to be an active link, not just the text:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- table,
    tr,
    td {
      width: 100%;
      background: gray;
    }
    
    a {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      font-size: 24px
    }
    -->
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to change the order of the HTML elements. This must be solved only by CSS/Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `display: flex;` to `a` in the CSS:

```html
 <html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
     <!--
     table, tr, td {width: 100%;background: gray;}
     a {width:100%;
       text-align:left;
       color:white;
       background-color:black;
       font-size: 24px;
       display: flex;
       }
     -->
     </style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
   <tr>
     <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just figuring out that adding: a {display:block;} works. Similar solution

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display:block` could do it.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- table,
    tr,
    td {
      width: 100%;
      background: gray;
    }
    
    a {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      font-size: 24px;
      display:block
    }
    -->
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```